# Regex to remove from the beginning of the string '[' from the end ']'

Tags: python, regex

I've been trying desperately to make this work but it doesn't remove the first characters.

```
 [13, 45] # What I have
 13, 45   # What I want
```

and my regex: `re.sub(r"^\s*([\s*)?|(\s*[)?\s*$",'',string)`

Comment: aren't you trying to parse a python list by chance ?

Comment: No I have a string which its format is like a list and want to convert it to a list but first I need to remove the characters [] and then split the string.

Comment: See https://ideone.com/ZxCj8l, `ast.literal_eval(s)`.

Comment: You don't need regex for this. just do `"[13, 45]"[1:-1]'` otherwise just follow @maroun Maroun example

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` does that for you. No need for regex, no need for text processing

Comment: Why not `re.sub("[\[\]]", "", string)` ?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribizew Not what I asked. I need to do this with regex.

Comment: @user3807593 Using a regex for this is incredibly error-prone. What if your input is `[13, [45, 2]]`? What should the result be? This is a particular case of a general pattern for which regular expressions are badly suited.

Comment: /questions/14709557/how-to-remove-commas-brackets-in-python-using-regular-expression

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex does not work because you do not escape your last `[` (which should be `]` anyway. This should work:

```
re.sub(r"^\s*\[\s*|\s*\]\s*$",'',string)
```

Running this in the terminal gives:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> st=' [13, 45]'
>>> re.sub(r"^\s*\[\s*|\s*\]\s*$",'',st)
'13, 45'
```

Comment: That's it! You are the man.

Comment: @user3807593 accept his answer

Comment: You can just use `"[13, 45]"[1:-1]` but if you insist regex, use:    
`data = re.search("\[(.*?)\]",text).group(1)`

Comment: @Tushortz: there are three problems with this approach: (1) based on the question itself, the OP wants to remove space in the front and the back (the `\s*` in the initial regex), and (2) if you feed it something other than a list, it will fail, and (3) if you feed it a list of lists, like `[[1,2],[3,5]]`, it will return `[1,2` so semantically invalid. List processing with regex is in fact a bad idea because of the possibility of cascading, it is actually a context-free language.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Oh, i didn;t see it until after checking his regex. Thought it was just to remove a square bracket just like the answers below